# How to avoid Jagged edges using custom brush in sculpt mode

Tags: sculpting, brushes

I have made a custom brush. I have divided my mesh and has almost 1 million vertices. When I'm in sculpt mode, the custom brush pattern looks more smooth, when I exit sculpt mode the edges become jagged. The + Options gives a different result to the smooth edges of the pattern I have noticed, although its from the same mesh surface.

So is it possible to get a smoother edges on the brush pattern?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure that you can without a higher resolution or a Subdivision Surface modifier, of course you need to Shade Smooth, and maybe you could try the Smooth modifier but it will tend to dissolve the shape, but what do you mean by " The + Options gives a different result"?

Comment: Yes, you're correct, I also need to ad further more subdivision modifier, and smoothing, but my PC is not coping very well, with such a high polycount. Also when I get closer to the cube I can still see bad geometry, regardless so much subdivisions.

https://ibb.co/CvWQrGk

The + and - , I was referring to the direction next to the strength.

Comment: You can't avoid that, as I said maybe try the Smooth modifier and see if it gives a good result, also, if the relief is not deep and you want to avoid high-poly, use a bump or normal map to fake it?

Comment: Ill try that too, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing, of course you need to shade smooth. The result will depend on the resolution, the higher it will be the more you'll avoid this jagged effect. If you can't afford a high resolution and your relief is not too high you could fake your shape with a bump or a normal map, what you show is typically what you could do with bump or normal map. Another solution would be to use a *Smooth* or *Smooth Corrective* modifier, but the drawback is that it will tend to dissolve the shape:

[image]